# How to return count from table as 0 if row does not exist?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two tables.

Fruit:

```
   id  ||  name
 -----------------
    1  ||  oranges 
    2  ||  apples
```

And baskets:

```
 basket  ||  fruit references a.id
 ---------------------------------
    x    ||   1
    x    ||   1
    y    ||   1
    y    ||   2
```

I need to select the number of fruit using count(baskets.fruit) where basket is x. The part where I am confused is: if a basket does not contain an entry for a fruit, it needs to return 0.

So for example, if we need the counts of basket x, we would get:

```
fruit.name  ||  count
-------------------
  apples    ||  2
  oranges   ||  0
```

Note that despite oranges not existing for x in baskets, it still returns an entry as 0.

Comment: Show us your query so far. It would be easier for us to help you if you set up a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/), too.

Comment: This query is very easy to do, you have to show what you have tryed because some guys came in here just to get answers for their homework.

Comment: Do you have apples and oranges mixed up in your example?  I see basket `x` containing 2 oranges and 0 apples, but your sample output shows the opposite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make an [outer join](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) between your tables and then group accordingly:

```
SELECT   fruit.name, COUNT(baskets.fruit)
FROM     fruit LEFT JOIN baskets ON baskets.fruit = fruit.id
WHERE    baskets.basket = 'x'
GROUP BY fruit.id
```

Comment: +1. Your answer is better, because I missed the `WHERE` requirement in the question (and therefore didn't include it in my answer). Deleting mine, because editing to include that after you posted a more complete answer would be wrong. :-)

Comment: @KenWhite: Also I think your `SUM(COALESCE(b.fruit, 0))` would not produce the OP's desired results...

Answer (score 0):

We have 2 table ,(section) and (takes)
section of courses in a university... each course has 2 or 3 section and students can take a course by enrolling to the section... each section id that students enroll to it will insert to the takes table and each sections has not any enrollment can not be written in takes table and still exist just in section table .

the question that i solved was :

find the enrollments of each section but also include sections with no students taking them; the enrollment for such sections should treated as 0.

my query:

```
select distinct(section.sec_id),COUNT(section.sec_id) as enrollment
from takes,section
where section.sec_id = takes.sec_id
group by section.sec_id
union
(select sec_id , 0 
from section
where not exists ( select sec_id
from takes
where section.sec_id = takes.sec_id))
```

I hope that is be useful for you.